# System.IO.Ports 5.0 NuGet package does not work in my solution

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I'm getting quite desparate here. My project is stalled by problems getting System.IO.Ports to work in this .NET 5.0 solution on Windows. I have recently ported the whole application from VS2017/.NET Framework 4.6.1/WinForms to VS2019/.NET5/WPF. I didn't have this problem before the big operation.

If I create a new bare bone solution with a WPF application and a class library that uses System.IO.Ports it works perfectly.

The differences to the real solution are:

- The real solution uses other NuGet packages: Antlr4.Runtime.Standard 4.9.1, Antlr4BuildTasks 8.13, CommandLineParser 2.8, Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3, System.Reflection.Emit 4.7 and System.Resources.Extensions 5.0.0.
- The class library using System.IO.Ports is being dynamically loaded using reflection.
- The WPF application is using ActiproSoftware.Controls.WPF 20.1.1

The first thing showing something is wrong is there is no copy of System.IO.Ports.dll in the output folder after building. I tried adding a console application to the solution (also .NET Core 3.1 then changed to .NET5), a copy of System.IO.Ports.dll ***IS*** being copied to the output folder.
But the bare bone test solution does copy System.IO.Ports.dll to its output folder as expected, and in that it is a class library that has the dependency to System.IO.Ports.
Even if I add a new class library to the solution without adding any project references to its dependencies, no System.IO.Ports.dll is copied.

I add the System.IO.Ports 5.0.0 package to the project using "Manage NuGet Packages..." on the project in Solution Explorer.

I hope I can do some kind of resetting or cleanup of the solution to fix it, but I have no idea what to do.
For now I just need it to work on Windows.

I could also try creating the whole application from the ground up again and start adding the source files and dependencies until the problem shows again.
But for now I hope for some help :-)

It could very well be a trivial thing in the solution/project settings/configuration somewhere. I'm not strong in that part of .net development.

I'm not sure if it has anything to do with my problem, but I'm not sure if the .NET 5 SDK is 100% correct installed, because I don't have .NET5 project templates (and I don't know if I should have). I create projects of the ".NET Core" type and after creation I change the target framework to .NET 5.0. I did a complete reinstall, and it's the same. Everything else seems to work...

Cheers,
Jan

UPDATE

I might have confused things by falsely believing System.IO.Ports.dll should be copied to the output folder. I understand that it shouldn't.

I dont get any problems at build time. Everything works there.
The error I get at runtime, and the reason I started experimenting, is this:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Ports, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_Signature()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.FetchNonReturnParameters()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParameters()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.GetCallbackMethodsForType(Type type, List`1& onSerializing, List`1& onSerialized, List`1& onDeserializing, List`1& onDeserialized, List`1& onError)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveCallbackMethods(JsonContract contract, Type t)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.InitializeContract(JsonContract contract)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type objectType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.Get(TKey key)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type type)
   at StepBro.Core.Parser.StepBroListener.CreateVariableContainerObjectInitAction(Type objectType, PropertyBlock properties, ErrorCollector errors, IToken startToken) in C:\SW_development\Private\StepBro\source\StepBro.Core\Parser\StepBroListener.cs:line 277
```

I have now tried re-installing the .NET5 runtime but gets the same error. Should I also uninstall the SDK or should I only install one of them ?
I can see two SDK installations in the Apps & features: MS .NET SDK 5.0.102 (x64) and one with the postfix "from Visual Studio".

UPDATE #2

It would be best if I created a new question, but here's the latest update on my discoveries.

System.IO.Ports is being used by my library StepBro.Streams. StepBro.Streams is loaded dynamically by StepBro.Core which is used by the WPF application.
I get the above error the moment an instance of one of the types in StepBro.Streams is created by StepBro.Core (through Newtonsoft.Json).

I'm not stuck anymore, because I have temporarily added a reference to System.IO.Ports from StepBro.Core. That way, the assembly is already loaded the moment reflection is used to create a type from StepBro.Streams (or System.IO.Ports).

So, there is a problem, **when dynamically loading the assembly**, and I have no idea what to do about it after all the reinstallations and different experiments I have done.
Maybe it's a problem with my VS2019 solution, with my installation of .NET5 or indeed a bug in .NET5.

Comment: There shouldn't be a copy of the System.IO.Ports in the build folder.  It should be part of the Net Library.  Looks like somebody with old version of code created a kludge to get old code working.  See following : https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/

Comment: Thanks, @jdweng. I'm not sure I'm getting wiser reading that page.

Comment: I would download latest version and then make sure you do a clean build.  Then install using following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/

Comment: What I forgot to say is that I don't get any compilation errors but at runtime I get an exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Ports, Version=5.0.0.0
I guess this is the real problem then...
I will give it a try and reinstall .NET5.

Comment: The Net library isn't looking for the dll in the bin folder.  As I said somebody tried to fix issue by putting the dll in the bin folder and it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I just added the missing explanation of what made me do some experimentation. I got confused when I saw that the console project copied the file. It makes sense that it is part of the installed framework.

Comment: Do you want to use StepBrow.Core?

Comment: Yes, that's the heart of my application :-)
Actually I have made a hot-fix, where I include the System.IO.Ports package in StepBro.Core. That's not desired, but I can live with it until I find the error.
I will add a new SO question shortly, because I have closed in on the real problem, thanks to your input.

Comment: There doesn't look like any known issues with Core 5.0 and serial ports (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/5.0).  Could issue be with the device you are using?  Maybe update the device kernel or a startup configuration file.

Comment: The error happens without opening any device.
I updated my question. It must be related to the dynamic loading. 
The devices has been used for a very long time and still works perfectly when doing the trick I describe.

Comment: You need to upgrade to Net 4.7.2 or later.  Net 4.7.2 allows you to target either Core or Net from same source code.  Using older version of Net you may get errors when using Core.

Comment: Thanks, @jdweng. I'm not sure what you mean. I am using .NET 5, and I will never look back :-)
It was that upgrade/migration that brought me this problem.

Comment: Upgrading becomes complicated.  Look at TLS.   TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 was made obsolete in June last year when Microsoft did a security Push on servers and disables the old version of TLS and required uses to use TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.  So what worked in Net 4.6.1 (uses TLS 1.0/1.1) does not work in Net 5.0 (uses TLS 1.2/1.3).  The Net 4.6.1 did the TLS in Net while Net 5.0 does TLS in operatin system.When using Nuget packages you have to make sure the libraries also have be updated to use Latest Net/Core libraries.  And meet following : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/5.0

Comment: I had the same problem, System.IO.Ports referenced in a sub-assembly failing to load dynamically. Adding a reference in the 'main' project fixed it. There *IS* a bug in 5.0

Answer (score 2):

> `Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Ports, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

The reflection loader is trying to load a `System.IO.Ports.dll` assembly and failing. I don't know what all that non-sense in comments about not needing the assembly binary to exist is, but the loader disagrees with both of you.

> System.IO.Ports is being used by my library StepBro.Streams

Then you packaged your library wrong. You want to export the dependency so that it is inherited by the host project.

Once that is done, the only remaining issue is that, because you never actually use the types exposed by the ports assembly directly, the compiler doesn't know that you actually use the library, so it will omit it from the generated binaries. You want to at least reference something in that assembly at some point, even a simple `typeof(SerialPort)`.

Comment: Since you took your time to write an answer I will politely comment on it.
I have all my experience from .Net2 to .Net4.6 and have developed a quite large application since 2006. In that application and also in my .Net4.6 version of my new application this has been working. The dynamically loaded assemblies (addons) expose whatever interface they need and use their own dependencies as necessary.
There's a lot I dont know about .Net Core and about packaging and deployment, but as I see it, the problem came with the migration to .Net5, and I hope some kind people can help me.

Comment: You’re not going to get much more help than this without an actual minimal reproducible project that we can run and debug. I would suggest posting on the .Net5 repository, but they’ll just close your question without a reproduction (and rightfully so).